# How to use Application.match?

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to Excel VBA.

I have these random columns:

```
Range("Y1").Value = "LITIGATE_PERSON_ADDRESS"
Range("Z1").Value = "LITIGATE_PERSON_CITY"
Range("AA1").Value = "LITIGATE_PERSON_TK"
Range("AB1").Value = "LITIGATE_PERSON_ADDRESS_TYPE"
```

Here's the part of code that is being used for these columns.

```
  Worksheets("MAIN_CONTROL").Cells(i, 25).Value = sourceADR

 sourceADR = Replace(sourceADR, "Attica", "")



 '...................................................................
  sourceADR = Replace(sourceADR, "-", " ")
  sourceADR = Replace(sourceADR, "  ", " ")
  sourceADR = Trim(sourceADR)

  auxC = sourceADR

Worksheets("MAIN_CONTROL").Cells(i, 26).Value = sourceADR
'..............................
  If (Len(sourceADR) < 1) Then GoTo aseAddr
'..............
 mainAddress = Split(sourceADR)

  addrAA = ""

Worksheets("MAIN_CONTROL").Cells(i, 24).Value = Str(UBound(mainAddress)) & "@@" & Str(LBound(mainAddress))


  For jA = UBound(mainAddress) To LBound(mainAddress) Step -1
 '......................................................


If (regex.Test(Trim(mainAddress(jA)))) Then

auxC = Replace(auxC, Trim(mainAddress(jA)), "")

 destws.Range("BT" & i).Value = Trim(mainAddress(jA))
 destws.Range("AA" & i).Value = Trim(mainAddress(jA))
 destws.Range("Z" & i).Value = addrAA

auxC = Trim(auxC)
 destws.Range("Y" & i).Value = auxC
'--------------------------------------------------------

'-------------------------------------------------------

GoTo aseAddr


 End If

auxC = Replace(auxC, Trim(mainAddress(jA)), "")
addrAA = mainAddress(jA) & " " & addrAA








'

 '.....................................................
 Next jA
 '.........................................................
  'destws.Range("Y" & i).Value = addrAA
'.....................
aseAddr:
'.................................
```

My problem is that these columns may change order.
I was suggested to use application.match so that my code may follow but i don't know how to put it inside my code.

Can anyone help?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I dont see how you use those columns in your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to SO.

In general, the way you can use an excel function in VBA is the following:

```
application.WorksheetFunction.Match() 'where match() can be replaced by one of the available worksheet functions.
```

The function's arguments work pretty much the same way as they do when you use the formula in your worksheet.

The Match functionality is explained thoroughly [here](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-match-function)

So for example let's say you have an array like the following one in cells `A1:A13`

[image]

And you want to find the location of "Friday". You would do it like so:

```
Debug.Print Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Friday", sht.Range("A1:A13"), 0)
```

And you would get `5` as a result.

That should pretty much cover the "How to use Application.Match()".

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.Thank you for the help. It helped me a lot!

Comment: Tipota dike mou ;) Consider accepting the answer if it did indeed answer your question.